# How to place bullet point for each element in a list

Tags: php, html

```
echo '<td width="11%" class="imagetd">';
if (empty($arrImageFile[$key])) {
    echo '&nbsp;';
} else {
    echo '<ul class="qandaul"><li>';
    echo htmlspecialchars(is_array($arrImageFile[$key]) ? implode("\n", $arrImageFile[$key]) : $arrImageFile[$key]);
    echo '</li></ul>';
}
echo '</td>';
```

In code above, I have a lit of image names, now each image name is seperated by  line break, but the problem I am having is that it does not display a bullet point for each image file name inserted in the line break. It is only displaying one bullet point for the first image name and that is it. In example above how do I insert a bullet point for each image name?

**UPDATE**

Does CSS take effect below:

`ul, ul li { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
ul { margin-left: 1.3em; }`

Below refers to Juan's answer which I want to make sure is correct as it did not work:

```
echo '<td width="11%" class="imagetd">';
if (is_array($arrImageFile[$key]) {
    foreach($arrImageFile[$key]  as $img)  {
        if (empty($arrImageFile[$key])) {
            echo '&nbsp;';
        } else {
            echo '<ul class="qandaul"><li>';
            echo '<li>' . htmlspecialchars($img) . '</li>'
        }
    }          
    echo '</li></ul>';
}
echo '</td>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting all your image files inside the `<li>`. Create a separate `<li>` for each image

```
echo '<ul class="qandaul>';
if (empty($arrImageFile[$key])) {
    echo '<li>&nbsp;</li>';
} else {
    if (is_array($arrImageFile[$key]) {
        foreach($arrImageFile[$key] as $img)  {
            echo '<li>' . htmlspecialchars($img) . '</li>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<li>' . htmlspecialchars($arrImageFile[$key]) . '</li>';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

or you can use the array implode trick others have suggested. I tend to think that is less readable.

```
echo implode("</li>\n<li>", array_map(function($item){
    return htmlspecialchars($item);
},  $arrImageFile[$key]));
```

Comment: Both instances did not work, can you please look at my update. Sorry for lateness btw

Comment: @user1830984 I've updated my code with a more complete snippet. It would take too long to explain each problem with your attempt.

Comment: The first block of code doesn't work, it makes the column dissapear with first block of code you shown

Comment: @user1830984 I'm sure the first snippet would have worked, you probably forgot the part about opening and closing the `<td>`. You did confuse things quite a bit when you created your snippet using my suggestion. You should never just paste code, be sure to understand what you're putting into your code

Comment: Sorry, late to the party, but I had the same problem, and figured it out from the above. Because you are imploding by `</li>\n<li>`, the string output should start with the opening `<li>` and be terminated with the closing `</li>` after the imploding, otherwise your first item will not have an opening `<li>` and your last item will not have a closing `</li>`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `implode("\n", $arrImageFile[$key])`,

use `implode("</li>\n<li>", $arrImageFile[$key])`,

the point is you need to create one `li` for one image.

```
echo '<td width="11%" class="imagetd">';
if (empty($arrImageFile[$key])) {
    echo '&nbsp;';
} else {
    echo '<ul class="qandaul"><li>';
    echo htmlspecialchars(is_array($arrImageFile[$key]) ? implode("</li>\n<li>", $arrImageFile[$key]) : $arrImageFile[$key]);
    echo '</li></ul>';
}
echo '</td>';
```

Comment: Sorry for lateness, I tried this but it did not work, it is still doing same thing

Answer (score 0):

It's because everything is wrapped in one `<li>` tag. `echo '<ul class="qandaul"><li>';`

Put each in it's own `<li>`

Answer (score 0):

A pointed list markup in html is:

```
<ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

So you'll have to implode with "</li><li>" or use a for loop (or foreach).

Comment: imploding with just </li><li> did not change anything. Look at update to see if css takes affect

Answer (score -1):

The bullet points are dependent on your CSS style, please check what the CSS style says for ul and the class qandaul.

Comment: I included css in update, please have a look when you have time and update answer

Comment: Downvote, because imho this is not an answer... should be a comment.